# error message not displayed in protractor

Tags: typescript, function, jasmine, protractor

I'm running Protractor scripts in a Jasmine framework from Visual Studio Code V1.41.1, but can't seem to get the error handling code to execute.  The online help all seem to point to a format resembling this:

```
    elm.isDisplayed().then(function() { /* passing case */}, function(err) { /* error handling here */})
```

I attempted to use this type of format in my actual script, but I can't get the results I'm expecting.  As far as I can see, this is just a binary choice...  Either the header is displayed, or it's NOT displayed.  If it's displayed, the code checks to see that the number of records displayed in the results table matches the number of records displayed in the header.  If it's NOT displayed, then a message is displayed that records were not found, and the test moves on to the next **it** block.  The code I'm using is this:

```
    it('  Verified: Search results record count matches the expected total', function () {

      let intTotalCount = 0;
      let intRecordCount = 0;
      // See if the Search Results "items in the list" header is displayed
      reportPage.getResultHeaderIsDisplayed()
        .then(function () {
            reportPage.getResultCount()
              .then(function (tCount: any) {
                intTotalCount = tCount;

                return intTotalCount;
              })

              .then(function (rCount: any) {
                reportPage.getSRCount();
                intRecordCount = rCount;

                return intRecordCount;
              })

              .then(function () {
                console.log('          Expect: ' + intRecordCount + ' = ' + intTotalCount);

                if (!(intRecordCount === intTotalCount)) {
                  console.log('***   ERROR:  Number of records DOES NOT match the expected total');
                }

                expect(intRecordCount).toEqual(intTotalCount);
              })
        }, function (msg) {
          msg = "Records Not Found!"
          console.log("\n        *** " + msg + " ***\n");
        })
    });
```

The special function calls I'm using include:

```
    // PO File:
    // Items Found Header:
    resultHeader = element(by.xpath('//body//h5[not(@class="ng-hide")]'));

    // Search Results Count:
    public getResultHeaderIsDisplayed() {
      this.browserHelper.wait('//h3[@class="panel-title"]', 'xpath');
      return this.navigationHelper.isElementDisplayed(this.resultHeader);
    }


    // Navigation Helper:
    async isElementDisplayed(ele: ElementFinder) {
      return await ele.isDisplayed();
    }
```

If search results are found, the expected table information is displayed and the code works just fine.  If no results are found, though, a red "No Records Found" banner is displayed.  What I was trying to accomplish is just displaying a simple "Records Not Found!" message in the output window.  What I actually get is this (and the expected message is NOT displayed)...

```
    ×   Verified: Search results record count matches the expected total
      - Failed: Wait timed out after 20420ms
          at C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2201:17
          at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
          at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
          at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
          at asyncRun (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
          at C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
          at <anonymous>
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
      From: Task: <anonymous wait>
          at scheduleWait (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2188:20)
          at ControlFlow.wait (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2517:12)
          at Driver.wait (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:934:29)
          at run (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:59:33)
          at ProtractorBrowser.to.(anonymous function) [as wait] (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:67:16)
          at BrowserHelper.wait (C:\Users\Ops-UI\apps\safe-e2e\src\helpers\browser.helper.ts:55:30)
          at reportPage.getResultHeaderIsDisplayed (C:\Users\Ops-UI\apps\e2e\src\pageobjects\report.po.ts:1055:28)
          at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ops-UI\apps\e2e\src\specs\verify-report.e2e-spec.ts:435:25)
          at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
          at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
          at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
          at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
          at asyncRun (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2974:25)
          at C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
      From: Task: Run it("  Verified: Search results record count matches the expected total") in control flow
          at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
          at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
      From asynchronous test:
      Error
          at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ops-UI\apps\e2e\src\specs\verify-report.e2e-spec.ts:431:5)
          at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ops-UI\apps\e2e\src\specs\verify-report.e2e-spec.ts:45:1)
          at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
          at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
          at Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
          at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\Users\Ops-UI\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)          at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
          at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
          at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
          at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
          at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

As you can see, I get a stack dump which tells me nothing other than the fact that it tried to find the header object, couldn't find it, and timed out after 20420ms, but the expected error message is ignored.  How can I get rid of the stack dump and just display the message?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is pretty simple, your jasmine test does not know about your async commands, and just reaches end of `it` block and thinks thats the end of the test.

You need to return promise that will be resolved when your test complete OR use async/await and promise will be returned implicitly, here is docs:
https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async

For you fix will be super-simple, just add `return` to your promise chain:

```
it('  Verified: Search results record count matches the expected total', function () {

  let intTotalCount = 0;
  let intRecordCount = 0;
  // notice return added!
  return reportPage.getResultHeaderIsDisplayed().then(
    ... rest of code...
});
```

But i will strongly suggest to rewrite code to use async/await everywhere and set SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false in your config.

Look how cleaner your code can be:

```
it('  Verified: Search results record count matches the expected total', async function () {
    await reportPage.getResultHeaderIsDisplayed();
    const intTotalCount = await reportPage.getResultCount();
    const intRecordCount = reportPage.getSRCount();
    expect(intRecordCount).toEqual(intTotalCount, '***   ERROR:  Number of records DOES NOT match the expected total');
});
```